# Flatpickr always saves the current datetime

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm using Flatpickr for a field in my form called `trigger_date`:

```
.form-group
  = label f, :trigger_date, class: "control-label"
  = text_input f, :trigger_date, required: true, class: "form-control datetime-picker"
```

No matter which date I pick the form will always submit the current date and time. This is my current setup of `Flatpickr`:

```
const flatpickr = require("flatpickr");
const moment = require("moment");
const $this= $(this)
let defDate = moment().format()

const dateString = $this.val()
if (dateString != NaN && dateString != "NaN" && dateString != null && dateString != undefined && dateString.length > 0) {
    defDate = moment().format()
}

const picker = flatpickr($this[0], {
  enableTime: true,
  defaultDate: defDate,
  dateFormat: "Z",
  altInput: true,
  weekNumbers: true,
  minuteIncrement: 1
});
```

Comment: i have this problem too, please let us know if you come up with a solution.

Comment: @Volkan Kahyaoğlu removing `altInput` resolved the issue, but you have to come up with a way to format the date on the front-end.